# Installing libsystemd headers

Tags: apt, systemd, development

I want to install `libsystemd` headers, but I can't.

output of `apt-cache policy systemd`:

```
# apt-cache policy systemd
systemd:
  Installed: 229-4ubuntu13
  Candidate: 229-4ubuntu13
  Version table:
 *** 229-4ubuntu13 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     229-4ubuntu4 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Here is the output of `apt-cache policy libsystemd0`:

```
# apt-cache policy libsystemd0
libsystemd0:
  Installed: 229-4ubuntu13
  Candidate: 229-4ubuntu13
  Version table:
 *** 229-4ubuntu13 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     229-4ubuntu4 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Here is what happens when I do `apt-get install libsystemd-dev`:

```
# apt-get install libsystemd0 libsystemd-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libsystemd0 is already the newest version (229-4ubuntu13).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsystemd-dev : Depends: libsystemd0 (= 229-4ubuntu4) but 229-4ubuntu13 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Ouput of `grep "^deb " /etc/apt/sources.list`

```
# grep "^deb " /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: What's happens when you run `sudo apt remove libsystemd0`? if it does not remove other packages, remove it then install it again like: `sudo apt install libsystemd0=229-4ubuntu4`. after that try installing `libsystemd-dev` using `sudo apt install libsystemd-dev`

Comment: Here is another thing, I think  your `sources.list` got some issues, add the output of `grep "^deb " /etc/apt/sources.list` to your question before testing above command.

Comment: Did you run those commands ? If so and the error persists then it is a problem of dependencies and you will either need to re-write the package info or file a bug report.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, yes I did. It didn't help

Comment: Then it is a problem with packaging and you will need to file a bug report against the -dev package

Comment: @0x90 Have you tried what I suggest? I guess it will fixes your issue ...

Comment: @Ravexina not yet, but it sounds right, though a bit risky. I don't want to upgrade distribution

Comment: @0x90 It does not upgrade your Ubuntu, it just updates you packages to last version to get the last bug fixes and security patches. that is what you should always do. at the end you still are running Ubuntu xenial 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

Your source file is incomplete, get a backup from it:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list{,.my-bk}
```

then open it using nano:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add these lines into it:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main universe multiverse
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt update
```

after that try installing your desired package.

If you still got problem then first try upgrading your system:

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

or fixing dependencies, if there is any:

```
sudo apt install -f
```

Comment: It is a dependency problem not a repository problem. See "http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages"

Comment: Check it's repositories, it does not have `xenial-updates`

Comment: @bodhi.zazen So it shouldn't work on my system too right? (I'm running xenial too), but my system is update and it works fine. his source is outdated.

Comment: IMO You should not need to enable the updates repository to fix problems in main. Although this might work, should file a bug report against the package in main.

Comment: So isn't release-update there to fix the Main issues? (PS: the other day I was reading your PDF on fstab, thanks. it  was a good resource)

Comment: And as I know, release (xenial in this case) always is frozen after release date all updates and bug fixs will go on xenial-update they will not be applied in xenial.

Comment: Yes and no. Packages have a life cycle and main is the most stable. New updates are tested before they are added to main.

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories , the primary repos   are main, universe, multiverse, and restricted. The additional repos make packages available earlier , without as much testing, before they hit the primary repos. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories#A_Quick.2C_Tongue-in-cheek_Description_of_the_Ubuntu_Repositories . So you may get packages earlier, but with bugs. At any rate, the package in main should not have this problem.

Comment: Glad you liked the fstab pdf. I have additional stuff on my website if you so desire.

Comment: I'm actually talking about this sections: `xenial`, `xenial-updates` and `xenial-security`. from my knowledge `xenial` is frozen so if there is a bug in any component of `xenial` say `main` or `universe` it will be applied at `main` component but in `xenial-updates` and OP does not have it enabled. I don't know if I'm wrong :/

Comment: Yep got it from your website, bunch of cool stuff was there ;) will read them too :)

Comment: As I understand the process, updated packages are first placed in xenial-{security,updates} and after sufficient testing eventually placed in main. In general I have no problem with the security repo, but the updates repo has a slight chance of introducing both bugs as well as bug fixes, but I do not know the exact details of how packages move between the repos.

Comment: Mines comes from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/907266/264781). and from [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/FAQ#How_are_components_and_pockets_used_in_the_builds.2C_and_how_do_they_affect_security_updates.3F) it says release (in our case `xenial`) : during the development cycle, this is the only pocket that is used. Once the development version is released, the release pocket is frozen and does not change.

Comment: See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/UpdateProcedures

Comment: I couldn't find anything related to packages being updated in main repository (`release`) or how procedure moves the packages between say `xenial` and `xenial-updates.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how you got version 229-4ubuntu13 of the systemd libraries with these package sources. The only version in Xenial "release" is 229-4ubuntu4. There are newer versions in "security" (229-4ubuntu10) and "updates" (229-4ubuntu17) which don't match yours either.

You can either roll back to the packages in the "release" repository or enable the "updates" repository and upgrade the packages on your system.

### Roll back

- If you know all the systemd packages installed on your system you can use the following command:

  ```sh
  sudo apt-get install {<PACKAGE>,<PACKAGE>,...}=229-4ubuntu4
  ```
- If you don't know them you can use the following command to parse package descriptions and the list of installed packages to select and install them for you:

  ```sh
  apt-cache showsrc systemd |
  sed -nre '/^Package-List:/,/^\S/{s/^ (\S+) .*$/\1/p;}' | sort -u |
  xargs dpkg-query -Wf '${Status;1} ${Package}\n' 2>&- |
  sed -nre 's/^i (\S+)$/\1=229-4ubuntu4/p' |
  xargs sudo apt install
  ```

### Upgrade

1. Enable the "updates" repository.

   Open *Software Properties*, navigate to the *Updates* tab and enable the checkbox for *Recommended updates*.

   [image: software properties screenshot]
2. Update the package list and perform a system upgrade:

   ```sh
   sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For me I manually searched for libsystemd in apt cache using `sudo apt search libsystemd` which returned libsystemd-dev which is libsystemd development files, libsystemd0 which are utility libraries for systemd and lua-systemd which are system bindings for lua.
I then installed them using `sudo apt install libsystemd0 libsystemd-dev`.
I didn't include lua-systemd since I don't really understand why or if I needed it.
After that I did not get the same error I was getting ( "Unable to find a matching distribution for libsystemd and libsystemd-dev") when I ran `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`
Hope this helps someone.